# Reverse for 'unassign_emp' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['unassign\\-emp/(?P<eid>[^/]+)/\\Z']

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have two views: one to show the list of assigned users and post method to assign new users.
Second view: to delete a user from usecase_assigned table

I’m showing everything in one template, and pressing delete button It’s executing another view and redirecting to the same page (UsecaseDetails.html):

model:

```
class UsecaseAssign(models.Model):
    usecase_assign_date = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True, auto_now_add=True)
    usecase = models.ForeignKey(Usecase, models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_email = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_email')
    usecase_role_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

my views:

```
@user_login_required
def view_usecase_details(request, ucid):
    usecase_details = Usecase.objects.filter(usecase_id=ucid).all()
    usecase_details = usecase_details.prefetch_related("usecaseids")
    users = User.objects.all() #SELECT user_email FROM usecase_assign WHERE usecase_id LIKE 'NN245';
    usecase_assigned = UsecaseAssign.objects.select_related('user_email').values_list('user_email__user_name').filter(usecase_id=ucid) #to show list of users working on uc
 
    if request.method=='POST' and 'assignuser' in request.POST:
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        userAssignCheck = UsecaseAssign.objects.filter(user_email=user_email, usecase_id=ucid)
        if userAssignCheck:
            messages.error(request, "user already added!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usecase-details', args=[ucid]))
        else:
            userAssignObj = UsecaseAssign.objects.create(user_email_id=user_email, usecase_id=ucid)
 
        if userAssignObj:   
            messages.success(request, "User was Successfully Assigned with Usecase!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usecase-details', args=[ucid]))
 
    context = {'usecase_details': usecase_details, "users": User.objects.all(), 'usecase_assigned':usecase_assigned, "users": users}
    return render(request, 'UsecaseDetails.html', context)      ##ask in stack overflow with pic of url how to pass only the id clicked   
 
@user_login_required
def unassign_emp(request, eid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        unassign_emp = UsecaseAssign.objects.get(user_email=eid)
        unassign_emp.delete()
        messages.success(request, "User was unassigned with Usecase!")
    return redirect('myapp:usecase-details')
```

my template:

```
{% for result in usecase_details %}
<div class="card card-body shadow-sm mb-4 mb-lg-0">
    <form class="mb-card" action="{% url 'usecase-details' ucid=result.usecase_id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row mb-4">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
            <label class="h5" for="user_email">Assign new users:</label>
            <select name="user_email" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="user">
                <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                {% for user in users %}
                <option value="{{ user.user_email }}">{{ user.user_name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}                            
              </select>   
            </div>
       </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="assignuser" value="Submit Changes">
      </form>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between px-0 border-bottom">
            <div>
                <label class="mb-card h5" for="user_email">Assigned users:</label>
                {% for user in usecase_assigned %}
                <p>{{user|join:', '}}</p>
            <form action="{% url 'unassign_emp' usecase_assigned.user_email %}" method="POST" style="display: inline !important;">
              {% csrf_token %}
             <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
            </div>         
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

urls:

```
    path('usecase-details/<str:ucid>', av.view_usecase_details, name="usecase-details"),
    path('unassign-emp/<str:eid>/', av.unassign_emp, name="unassign_emp"),
```

Comment: is ```usecase_assigned.user_emai```l a nullable filed?

Comment: also share the full error traceback

Comment: user_email is the id of my User model so no

Comment: if I go and <form action="{% url 'unassign_emp' usecase_assigned%}" method="POST" style="display: inline !important;"> I get my url as: http://localhost:8000/unassign-emp/%3CQuerySet%20%5B('Norah',),%20('Elie%20C.',),%20('Salwa',),%20('Aktham',),%20('Anis',),%20('Ahod',),%20('A.%20Alatir',),%20('Albatool%20A.',)%5D%3E/ I need to get the id of clicked user only in order to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the for loop, change `usecase_assigned.user_email` to `user.user_email`

```
{% for user in usecase_assigned %}
...

<form action="{% url 'unassign_emp' user.user_email %}" method="POST" style="display: inline !important;">
...

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: tried this before got this error: Reverse for 'unassign_emp' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['unassign\\-emp/(?P<eid>[^/]+)/$']
not sure why it's getting an empty string from user.user_email

Comment: first of all make sure you have user.user_email is not null by cross checking in the Django admin, then make sure this form is exactly causing the error, you might have other places where you defined url 'unassing_emp' might also cause error, and the try to print user and user.user_email in that for loop for debugging( make sure that form is removed while debugging)